# Change the session time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i need to add more time session life time . but cant add more 10-12 days

```
 /**
 * Logs in the user by saving user details and setting session
 *
 * @param username
 * @param fullName
 */
public void loginUser(String username, String fullName) {
    mEditor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    mEditor.putString(KEY_FULL_NAME, fullName);
    Date date = new Date();

    //Set user session for next 7 days
    long millis = date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 *60 * 1000);
    mEditor.putLong(KEY_EXPIRES, millis);
    mEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: because `30 * 24 * 60 *60 * 1000` is being evaluated as an `int`... and it is overflowing, returning a negative value in this case... should have used `long` literal(s) instead (`30L * 24 * 60 *60 * 1000`)

Comment: BTW it is highly recommended not to use the `Date` class anymore... outdated since Java 8 by the `java.time` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the actual value of the milliseconds you want. Convert from days to milliseconds for instance, in a clearer way.

```
long millis = date.getTime() + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.DAYS);
//this will add 30 days
```

You can change the 30 to whatever days you'd prefer.

Comment: my problem has solved